# numColumns breaks scrollToIndex react native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using react native's [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) to display a list of items, and also check which items are currently viewable. In my items there's one item which is marked `mostUsed` if the item is not viewable I display a link at the top, the user can click that and scroll to that item, using `scrollToIndex`. `scrollToIndex` works well without setting `numColumns`, when I set `numColumns={2}` I get `scrollToIndex out of range: 9 vs 4` error.

```
setScrollIndex = () => {
  if (this.state.scrollIndex !== 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
    const items = this.state.items;

      if (items[i] && items[i].mostUsed) {
        this.setState({
          scrollIndex: i,
        });
      }
  }
};

// scroll to index function
scrollToIndex = () => {
  this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({
    animated: true,
    index: this.state.scrollIndex,
  });
};

<FlatList
  data={this.state.items}
  numColumns={2}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  ref={ref => {
    this.flatListRef = ref;
  }}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  onViewableItemsChanged={this.handleViewableItemsChanged}
  viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <Card  
      title={item.title}
      description={item.description}
      mostUsed={item.mostUsed}
      style={{ width: item.width }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

[expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/react-native-scrolltoindex-and-onviewableitemschanged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `FlatList`'s `scrollToIndex` changes the way it views index if `numColumns` is higher then 1.

It may be more correct to call it `scrollToRowIndex` since it does not work on item index in case of multiple columns.

For your case this worked for me on expo:

```
scrollToIndex = () => {
  this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({
    animated: true,
    index: Math.floor(this.state.scrollIndex / numColumns),
  });
};
```

Comment: Up vote this!!!! Thank @Moti azu

We can improve this answer by replacing `2` by numOfColumns

Comment: @Steffi Good idea